# Priority Queue and Heap (It's difficult to me..)

Tags: c, queue, heap

I want to complete this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HEAP_LEN 100
#define MAX_HEAP 20

struct heapElem{
  int priority;
  char* data;
};

struct _heap{
  int num_data;
  struct heapElem heapArr[HEAP_LEN];
};

int GetPriIdx(struct _heap* ph, int idx);
void swapD(char* a, char* b); 
void swapI(int* a, int* b);
void swap(struct heapElem a, struct heapElem b);
void Insert(struct _heap* ph, char* data, int priority);
void Delete(struct _heap* ph);
void Printout(struct _heap* ph);
void Retrieve(struct _heap* ph);
void KeyIncrease(struct _heap* ph, int priority, int n_priority);

int main(void) {
  struct _heap heap;
  heap.num_data = 0;

  char option_char;
  char name[20];
  int k_value;
  int new_k_value;

  do{
    printf("\n*********** MENU ***************\n");
    printf("I : Insert new element into queue\nD : Delete element with largest key from queue\nR : Retrieve element with largest key from queue\nK : Increase key of element in queue\nP : Print out all elements in queue\nQ : Quit\n\nChoose menu :");
    scanf("%c", &option_char);

    switch(option_char){
      case 'I' : //insert new element into queue
        printf("Enter name of element : ");
        scanf("%s", name);
        printf("Enter key value of element : ");
        scanf("%d", &k_value);
        Insert(&heap, name, k_value);

        break;

      case 'D' : 
        Delete(&heap);
        break;

      case 'R' : 
        Retrieve(&heap);
        break;

      case 'K' : 
        printf("Enter idx of element : ");
        scanf("%d", &k_value);
        printf("Enter new key value : ");
        scanf("%d", &new_k_value);
       KeyIncrease(&heap, k_value, new_k_value);
       break;

     case 'P' : 
        Printout(&heap);
        break;

     default:
          break;

    }


  }while(option_char != 'Q');
  return 0;
}


void swapD(char* a, char* b) {

    char temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;

}

void swapI(int* a, int* b) {

    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;

}


void Insert(struct _heap* ph, char* data, int priority){
  if(ph->num_data >= MAX_HEAP) return;

  int idx = ph->num_data+1;

  ph->heapArr[idx].data = data;
  ph->heapArr[idx].priority = priority;
  printf("?? instant %d: [%s, %s] \n", idx, ph->heapArr[idx].data, ph->heapArr[idx/2].data);



  while(idx >1 && ph->heapArr[idx].priority > ph->heapArr[idx/2].priority){
    if(priority > ph->heapArr[idx/2].priority){ 
      swapD(ph->heapArr[idx/2].data, ph->heapArr[idx].data);
      swapI(&ph->heapArr[idx/2].priority, &ph->heapArr[idx].priority);
      idx = idx/2;
    }
    else break;
  }

  ph->num_data += 1;
  printf("New element [%s, %d] is inserted.\n",data, priority);

}
```

I have a question about function 'Insert':

In this

```
ph->heapArr[idx].data = data;
ph->heapArr[idx].priority = priority;
```

Not priority, 
I only put 'data in idx (like this `ph->heapArr[idx].data = data`), but all data in `ph->Arr` changes value.

Only data is changed in all `ph->Arr`.

So, first Insert [cat, 5] second Insert [dog,9] then, it prints [dog, 9] [dog, 5]

Please help me ㅠㅠ

Answer (score 0):

In insert, when you do:

```
ph->heapArr[idx].data = data;
```

you assign the *pointer* `data` to the heap element. But you must *copy* the data because otherwise all heap elements point to the *same* `data` (which is `name` in your main).

So you should do:

```
ph->heapArr[idx].data = malloc(strlen(data)+1);
strcpy(ph->heapArr[idx].data, data);
```

or you could use `strdup`, which does this for you:

```
ph->heapArr[idx].data = strdup(data);
```

Comment: Really Really Thank you!! :> Your answer is very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

When you use this `ph->heapArr[idx].data = data;` you are not copying any data in

`ph->heapArr[idx].data` you are pointing it to the data that the function's argument also points to.

If you change that data`(in main function)`, then you will also change the `ph->heapArr[idx].data`, 
since you are sotring address of variable `name` in this pointer `ph->heapArr[idx]` ,though you can change variable `name` value ,but all of this array `ph->heapArr[idx]` will still point to value stored in variable `name` address ,so they will all change.

use `malloc` to first allocate memory for this pointer then instead of pointing it to another variable store data in it(copy data not just poniting to data)

```
ph->heapArr[idx].data = malloc(strlen(data)+1);
strcpy(ph->heapArr[idx].data, data);
```

Comment: Really Really Thank you!! :> Your answer is very helpful to me.

Comment: @Yeong Feel free,There is no need for thanks.if it really helped you accept the answer.